# IIS 5.1, Windows Authentication, Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, active-directory

There is a server (btw it's my workstation and is not really server) (WinXP SP3 Pro) with installed IIS 5.1 in the domain D.

I put a simple html file to Inetpub\wwwroot and set this file as default page for default web site. Now I want only my AD account to have access to view content of that file.

How can I configure IIS without writing any lines of code?

I can do it with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider or SqlRoleProvider. But I hope there is an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch off anonymous access and enable NTLM in IIS. On the file system, allow only your account read access to the file.

It should look like this:
[image: Screenshot]